# How can I load a Tensorflow SavedModel in Java with 'predict' Sgnature Def?

Tags: java, tensorflow

I'm training a Tensorflow Estimator and use `export_saved_model` to save the model in SavedModel format. Now I want to load this model with Tensorflow Java API (I don't want to use an model-server, I need to directly load it in Java). 
Now the problem is that `Estimator.export_saved_model` only exports the 'predict' signature_def, while the `SavedModelBundle` in Java seems to only support models with a 'serving_default' signature def.
So the question is: is there a way to make `Estimator.export_saved_model` to include the 'serving_default' signature def? Or is it possible to load the model with the 'predict' signature def in java? or are there any other options I could try?

Here is the code for exporting the model:

```py
feature_cols = [
        tf.feature_column.numeric_column('numeric_feature'),
        tf.feature_column.indicator_column( tf.feature_column.categorical_column_with_vocabulary_list('categorial_text_feature', vocabulary_list=['WORD1', 'WORD1']))
]

estimator = tf.estimator.LinearRegressor(
    feature_columns=feature_cols,
    model_dir=model_dir,
    label_dimension=1)

    estimator.train(input_fn=input_fn)

serving_input_receiver_fn = tf.estimator.export.build_raw_serving_input_receiver_fn({
        'numeric_feature': tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=(None,)),
        'categorial_text_feature': tf.placeholder(tf.string, shape=(None,))
})
estimator.export_saved_model(
    export_dir_base=model_dir,
    serving_input_receiver_fn=serving_input_receiver_fn)
```

If I inspect the model with `saved_model_cli show --tag_set serve` I get:

```
The given SavedModel MetaGraphDef contains SignatureDefs with the following keys:
SignatureDef key: "predict"
```

And with `saved_model_cli show --tag_set serve --signature_def predict`:

```
The given SavedModel SignatureDef contains the following input(s):
  inputs['numeric_feature'] tensor_info:
      dtype: DT_FLOAT
      shape: (-1)
      name: Placeholder:0
  inputs['categorial_text_feature'] tensor_info:
      dtype: DT_STRING
      shape: (-1)
      name: Placeholder_1:0
The given SavedModel SignatureDef contains the following output(s):
  outputs['predictions'] tensor_info:
      dtype: DT_FLOAT
      shape: (-1)
      name: linear/linear_model/linear_model/linear_model/weighted_sum:0
Method name is: tensorflow/serving/predict
```

And with `saved_model_cli show --tag_set serve --signature_def serving_default`:

```
The given SavedModel SignatureDef contains the following input(s):
The given SavedModel SignatureDef contains the following output(s):
Method name is:
```

Now when I load the model in Java and feed some values:

```
SavedModelBundle model = SavedModelBundle.load(modelPath, "serve");

Tensor<?> numericTensor = Tensors.create(new float[] { 10.3 });
Tensor<?> stringTensor = Tensors.create(new byte[][] { "WORD1".getBytes() });
Tensor<?> output = model
                .session()
                .runner()
                .feed("numeric_feature", numericTensor)
                .feed("categorial_text_feature", stringTensor)
                .fetch("predictions")
                .run()
                .get(0);
```

This results to following error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No Operation named [numeric_feature] in the Graph
    at org.tensorflow.Session$Runner.operationByName(Session.java:372)
    at org.tensorflow.Session$Runner.parseOutput(Session.java:381)
    at org.tensorflow.Session$Runner.feed(Session.java:131)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a (not perfect, but simple) workaround:

I just exported the model with `as_text=True`:

```py
estimator.export_saved_model(
        export_dir_base=model_dir,
        serving_input_receiver_fn=serving_input_receiver_fn,
        as_text=True)
```

and then just change the .pbtxt file by hand so that the signature def is called 'serving_default'